# Google Tag Manager Syntax Error

Tags: google-tag-manager

I added the Google Tag Manager code in my web page, but it is giving compilation Error.

These syntax errors are not in my page. Can any one help get rid of these errors.

Comment: This is not enough information. Be specific, show how you included the GTM code, check if the error is caused by a contained tag rather than GTM itself etc.

Comment: I added follwoing code at the end of body tag.  <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KWS7HK"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>

Comment: <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KWS7HK');</script>  When i remove this code from the page, it executes successfully

Comment: Compilation error? What is giving a compilation error? Screenshot? Exact text? What kind of website is it? Vanilla HTML? An application framework?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your container is published, even if it has no Tags, Triggers, Variables configured.

Add the Container script just after the opening < body > HTML Tag.

Get a clean copy of the GTM Container Script from Google Tag Manager > Admin > Install Google Tag Manager.